# Android: Force drawing order on GLSurfaceViews, SurfaceViews

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-framelayout, glsurfaceview

I have two GLSurfaceViews within a FrameLayout, as follows:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent" >

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id = "@+id/glSurfaceView1"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent" >

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id = "@+id/glSurfaceView2"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent" >


</FrameLayout>
```

When using the layout, **glSurfaceView2 is drawn before glSurfaceView1**. i.e. All you see on the screen is glSurfaceView1. This question was partially answered here:
[Android: FrameLayout not respecting draw order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602006/android-framelayout-not-respecting-draw-order)

I have already tried to dynamically add the GLSurfaceViews to the FrameLayout but this still doesn't draw in the correct order. Replacing FrameLayout with RelativeLayout doesn't work either.

So, how can I force the draw order so that **glSurfaceView1 is drawn before glSurfaceView2** (like it should)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce it from the layout, because the SurfaceView Surfaces are not composed by the app.  The layers are passed to the system compositor, which sees two layers attempting to occupy the same space at the same time, and chooses a winner.

You can select a Z-order for SurfaceView from a small set.  By default, the Surface is placed in the back, behind the View layer.  You can use [`setZOrderMediaOverlay()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean)) to put it between the View and the rear-most Surface, or [`setZOrderOnTop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)) to put it in front of everything.  These calls must be made before the Surface is created, usually in `onCreate()` of the activity class, before the `surfaceCreated()` callback fires.

(Note: GLSurfaceView is just a SurfaceView with some helper code for configuring EGL and managing threads.  AFAIK it doesn't interfere with the Z-order selection.)

You can find an example with three overlapping SurfaceViews in Grafika's "[multi-surface test](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MultiSurfaceActivity.java)".